# Schedule API Gateway requests with CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an API (through API Gateway) where each resource's method is routed to a single lambda function via lambda proxy integration, where each request is processed internally.

How can I automate a scheduled invocation of one resource's method with a CloudWatch event? This preferably will not be done by directly invoking the lambda function, and would allow a specified (constant) input.

Comment: I *suspect* that the only way to do this would be to create a new Lambda function that uses HTTPS to contact API Gateway, and invoke that with CloudWatch.  Or, depending on how often you want it invoked, e.g. multiple times per minute, you could use a Route 53 HTTPS Health Check.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot If you submit your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since CloudWatch Events does not support invoking an HTTP endpoint directly, you should be able to accomplish this by using SNS with a HTTP subscription. The workflow would be the following:

`Scheduled CloudWatch Event -> SNS endpoint with constant JSON payload -> HTTP subscription`, where the HTTP subscription is your API Gateway endpoint.